# Angular 2 UI Router not show view

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a little problem with Angular 2+ and UI Router.

I have 1 (only 1 in the whole system) `ui-view` in my app. When I declare all root states, everything is ok and works magically but when I declare child states, that doesn't load the component. The URL changes but component is not shown.

My code is:
App.component.html:

```
<div>
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

State declarations:

```
export const Ruteo: Ng2StateDeclaration[] = [
  { name: 'repartidores', url: '/Repartidores', component: RepartidoresComponent },
  { name: 'repartidores.alta', url: '/Nuevo', component: RepartidoresAltaComponent },
  { name: 'repartidores.modi', url: '/Modificar/{i}', component: RepartidoresModiComponent },

  { name: 'ayuda', url: '/Ayuda', component: AyudaComponent }
];
```

App.module.ts

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  UIRouterModule.forRoot({ states: Ruteo, useHash: true, config: Configurar }),
  HttpModule,
  FormsModule
],
```

I want ALL routes show the component in app component `ui-view`.

Sorry, my english is very bad...

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to work only with the latter.

*UI-Router views are placed into a ui-view that was created by the parent state. You must create a ui-view for the child to be placed into, or you can use view targeting to target the ui-view created in the root template.*

You can read the gory details about view targeting here: https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/interfaces/ng1.ng1statedeclaration.html#views

Comment: i tried **<ui-view name="root"></ui-view>** and all declarations like **{ name: 'repartidores', url: '/Repartidores', views: { root: { component: RepartidoresComponent } } }** and not work

Comment: I did than, but i need than the child use the same ui-view of the parent but not work like angularjs.

Comment: You cant, Child states DO inherit the following from parent states:

Resolved dependencies via resolve
Custom data properties
Nothing else is inherited (no controllers, templates, url, etc).

Comment: Years later, but ran into it today myself. Add an ! before root like so `{ name: 'repartidores', url: '/Repartidores', views: { '!root': { component: RepartidoresComponent } } }`